# Join two tables, check if one record in the first table matches with multiple records in the second

Tags: sql

I have two tables below, and I need to make a query that shows the first and last names of the students who have passed the course. In order to pass, they need to have completed these 8 units

'ISYS3356','COSC2446','COSC2385','COSC2510','COMM2326','COSC2511','ISYS2390','COSC2384'

and have a numerical grade >= 50.

I can't figure out how to check that all of the units are present.

```
STUDENTS (StudentID, FirstName, LastName,)
STUDENT_COURSES (StudentID, CourseCode, NumericalGrade)
```

```
SELECT S.FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM STUDENTS S,
     STUDENT_COURSES C
WHERE S.STUDENTID = C.STUDENTID
  AND NUMERICALGRADE >= 50
  AND COURSECODE IN ('ISYS3356','COSC2446','COSC2385','COSC2510','COMM2326','COSC2511','ISYS2390','COSC2384');
```

My query returns all rows, since all students are doing at least one subject. I can't figure out how to make it only show those who are doing ALL subjects. Can anyone help?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use distinct `count()` and explicit join

```
SELECT S.FIRSTNAME, S.LASTNAME
FROM STUDENTS S join STUDENT_COURSES C
on S.STUDENTID = C.STUDENTID
where NUMERICALGRADE >= 50
AND COURSECODE IN ('ISYS3356','COSC2446','COSC2385','COSC2510','COMM2326','COSC2511','ISYS2390','COSC2384')
group by S.FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
having count(distinct COURSECODE)=8
```